# Only real numbers (Fullsimplify)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've to do some complex calculation with Mathematica and if I put in my code it gives me something big back, so is it possible to say that my variables are strictly real numbers, by sing the FullSimplify option?

My code:

```
FullSimplify[Abs[(230)*((230)/(((((r)*(I*100*Pi*l))/((r)+(I*100*Pi*l)))*((s+t+(I*100*Pi*m)+(I*100*Pi*n))))/((((r)*(I*100*Pi*l))/((r)+(I*100*Pi*l)))+((s+t+(I*100*Pi*m)+(I*100*Pi*n))))))]]
```

And all my variables are real and bigger than zero (r,s,l,t,m,n)! How can I that fit in in my code to make the outcome more likeable, an option that makes my code as small as possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FullSimplify would be a start and reset variable/define variable

Comment: I've edited my last part, thanks for your comment

Comment: Fullsimplify is not FullSimplify

Comment: Oh I didn't know that

Comment: ComplexExpand. 15char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the documentation you see that [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) allows `Assumptions`, similar to [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) which could also help using [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
FullSimplify[
 ComplexExpand[
  Abs[(230)*((230)/(((((r)*(I*100*Pi*l))/((r) + (I*100*Pi*l)))*((s + 
             t + (I*100*Pi*m) + (I*100*Pi*
               n))))/((((r)*(I*100*Pi*l))/((r) + (I*100*Pi*
                l))) + ((s + t + (I*100*Pi*m) + (I*100*Pi*n))))))]]
 , Assumptions -> And @@ Thread[Greater[{r, s, t, m, n, l}, 0]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]